# What is this "project identifier" in ftok()?

Tags: linux, ipc, ftok

The second parameter `proj_id`. What is it?

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
key_t ftok (const char *pathname, int proj_id);
```

Comment: Please check it here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ftok.3.html

Comment: It is just an identifier. ftok uses the pathname and proj_id to create a unique value that can be used by different process to attach to shared memory or message queue or any other mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

There is a key and identifier based data structure with respect to the implementation of ftok ( where inode of the file from the path you gave and unique id associated with is attached).

So you can use any int value for proj_id so that the return value associcated with it will be common when referenced with same proj_id.

I tested it out by changing the proj_id and having the same file and then changing back to same proj_id (n-1). And my experiment worked. Where having same proj_id i was only be able assign 1 semaphore with the ftok key_id passed. But when I changed the proj_id and sending the same file path I was able to get new semaphore.
( remember to use nano for chaning as vim when using :wq option will change the inode number of the file).

For reference :
https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699969699/functions/ftok.html